# Fractal obtained from its "number of dimensions''.

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, fractals

Does the most regular fractal of a given dimension $r\in\mathbb{R}$ exist? Could I make one from its number $r$?

Comment: Please define "most regular".

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel that I had to downvote this question and vote to close, as it is not clear what it is that you are asking.  What do you mean by "most regular"?  How do you define the "regularity" of a fractal?  Also, what do you mean by "dimension"?  Hausdorff?  Minkowski-Bouligand?  Assouad? something else?  If you can clarify your question, I would happily retract my downvote and vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what the "most regular" fractal of a given dimension is.

If $0<r<n$ it's not hard to construct a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, analogous to a Cantor set, with Hausdorff dimension $r$.

How? Like so.

Suppose first that $0<r<1$. Choose $\alpha>0$ with $$\alpha^r=1/2,$$and note that $$\alpha<1/2.$$

If $I$ is an interval let $|I|$ denote the length of $I$. Given $I=[a,b]$, define $$I_L=[a,a+\alpha|I|],\quad I_R=[b-\alpha|I|,b].$$Then

> > If $I$ is a compact interval then $I_L\subset I$, $I_R\subset I$, $I_L\cap I_R=\emptyset$ and $|I_L|^r+|I_R|^r=|I|^r$.

Now construct a Cantor set $K$ as usual, starting with $I=[0,1]$, except: Instead of deleting the middle third of each interval at each step, replace each interval $I$ by the two intervals $I_L$, $I_R$. Note that

> > If $I_1,\dots I_{2^n}$ are the intervals remaining after the $n$th step then $\sum_{j=1}^{2^n}|I_j|^r=1$.

If $h_r$ is $r$-dimensional Hausdorff measure it's clear from the above that $$h_r(K)\le1.$$It's very plausible that $$h_r(K)>0;$$probably the cleanest way to prove this is using the trivial direction of Frostman's Lemmma, with the "uniform"  measure on $K$. So $$\dim(K)=r.$$

So we're done if $0<r<1$. Suppose that $0<r<n$. The construction above gives $K\subset\mathbb R$ with $\dim(K)=r/n$, and hence $\dim(K^n)=r$.

Comment: And the Cartesian product of a Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension $r$ and the unit cube $[0,1]^{n}$ will have dimension $r + n$, which gives a way of constructing sets of any positive real dimension.  This is not the most obvious technique, but it gets the job done.

Comment: Or to get something homeomorphic to a Cantor  set: If $K\subset\mathbb R$ has dimension $r$ then $K^n$ has dimension $nr$.

Comment: How I can do it?

Comment: @KelvynBrito See edit.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich, your supposition is wrong, because  $0< \alpha < \frac{1}{2}$ and $\alpha^r=\frac{1}{2}$ imply that $r>1$.

Comment: @KelvynBrito Do the arithmetic again. You seem to think that, for example, $\alpha^2>\alpha$. No, if $0<\alpha<1$ then $\alpha^2<\alpha,$ while $\alpha^{1/2}>\alpha$.